# Draw with Windows API

Tags: c++, windows

I develop this program that works fine and draws some figures to the screen:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cin.ignore();
    //Get a console handle
    HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
    //Get a handle to device context
    HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);

    //Choose any color
    COLORREF COLOR= RGB(255,255,255);
    HPEN hBluePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, COLOR);
    HGDIOBJ hPen = SelectObject(mydc, hBluePen);

    //Lines
    MoveToEx(mydc, 10, 40, NULL);
    LineTo(mydc, 44, 10);
    LineTo(mydc, 78, 40);

    //Rectangles
    cin.ignore();
    Rectangle(mydc, 16, 36, 72, 70);
    Rectangle(mydc, 60, 80, 80, 90);

    //Elipse
    cin.ignore();
    Ellipse(mydc, 40, 55, 48, 65);

    ReleaseDC(myconsole, mydc);
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

But when I resize or minimize the console all the drawed stuff disapear, someone could gave me an example of how this could be fixed?

Comment: Unrelated: Why `cin.ignore();`? Are you using it to pause and wait for the user to hit enter?

Comment: Yes it is just to pause and wait  for the user to hit enter.

Comment: May I suggest *not* writing platform specific code like this, and instead use a cross-platform library like [Qt](https://www.qt.io), [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org) or [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org) (or similar)? They are all (IMHO) easier to use than the raw Win32 API and they have the added benefit of working across Windows, Linux, MacOS and more with the same code - seems silly to me, to tie yourself to a single platform all the while making things harder than they have to be..

Comment: And how do I do this in SDL?

Comment: That's what I thought. Note that there is a bit of potential nastiness in a simple `ingore`. It doesn't care what character it gets. It will wait for a nerwline to push the data up , but if there is more than just the newline, it will be also consumed by `ignore`. Example input "aaaa" and hit enter. All of your `ignore`s will be satisfied and shoot through the program. Recommend adding `#include <limits>` and using `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` instead.

Comment: @user4581301 This is just for a testing purpose, but thank you by the sugestion

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have good answer for you. I suspect the answer is "You can't. You have to redraw." You could draw to a buffer and then draw the buffer, however. I don' t have enough experience with Win32 primitives to know how to do this.